# What's the better way to design a config file in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, configuration

I am doing a authorization in Spring Boot. I need a config file to save allowed group for each service. When Spring run, these data will be loaded in cache. Saved in things like

```java
Map<String_serviceName,Set<String_allowedGroup>>
```

I have a naive method in mind, create a config.properties. Save these in format like:

my.service.service_1=group_1,group_2,group_3...

my.service.service_2=group_1,group_2,group_3...

...

Is there any better way? Or it's enough for this need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work no doubt.
For better readability of your config you may consider using a yaml.

Although, below are my suggestions if you haven't tried them already

- user application-.yaml for have env specific configs Use
- spring's `@ConfigurationProperties` to map the entries directly to the objects
- (if possible) Use a DB table to store the configs